# Can't display returned JSON when using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, post

I am trying to retrieve the following json generated in my php script uing jquery. However, I am not being able to display it. If I alert it, it just displays 'undefined'. Using $('#demo').html(data.htmlOutput) to display the html doesn't do anything either. Please can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
$arr = array('htmlOutput' => '<b>hello</b>', 'no_rows' => 'balh');
echo json_encode($arr);

$.post('get-offers.php', $("#offerForm").serialize(), function(data) {
        alert (data.htmlOutput);
        alert (data.no_rows)
        $('#demo').html(data.htmlOutput);
}
```

I can see the json response in the FB console,however, it still does nothing.

Comment: How does the script know to parse it as JSON?

Comment: @BarryChapman. It should have known, see my answer below.

Comment: @gdoron - I was applying 'redirection'. I was hoping he might realize that he wasn't telling the script that it expected json and could have found the answer :)

Comment: @BarryChapman. jQuery team say in their docs they are doing _Intelligent Guess_ by default... so it could have worked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell jquery that you're expecting json, it's the last argument:

```
$.post('get-offers.php', $("#offerForm").serialize(), function(data) {
        alert (data.htmlOutput);
        alert (data.no_rows)
        $('#demo').html(data.htmlOutput);
}, "json");
```

Answer (score 2):

You Have tell jquery you are expecting `json` object, do it with the dataType as follows:

```
.post('get-offers.php', $("#offerForm").serialize(), function(data) {
        alert (data.htmlOutput);
        alert (data.no_rows)
        $('#demo').html(data.htmlOutput);
},'json'); //<====
```

> dataType: The type of data expected from the server.

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

I would think jquery will be able to guess it is a `json` object, because in their docs written:

> Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).

Well, I guess that that guess isn't that Intelligent... **=)**

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

First, set 'json' as the last parameter of you `$.post` to tell it that it is expecting a JSON response.

Second, before your first alert, add this:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

Then `alert(obj.htmlOutput);`

See if that works for you